# python: creating instance from variable name

Tags: python, class, instance

***EDIT2: Sorry about the broken code. Here is working code which illustrates the same issue:

```
class bead():
    def printmsg(a):
        print('test message')

chain1=bead()
x='chain1'
eval(x + '.printmsg()')
```

***EDIT: Thank you gnibbler for answering the original question. Here's a better worded version of my question:

```
class bead():
    def msg():
        print('test message')

x='chain1'
y='bead1'

eval(x + '.' + y + '=bead()')

chain1.bead1.msg()
```

output:
'test message'

What's a better way to do that?

Original question:

script:

```
class testClass():
    test1='test1 text'

x='testClass'
y='test1'

eval(x + '.' + y)
```

output:
'test1 text'

Is there a better way of doing this?

***EDIT: getattr() works for pulling the information from the class. Thank you gnibbler. Let me change the question a little bit though:

what could I use instead of:

x='chain1'
y='mol1'

Comment: do what? it really doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: I don't understand - your title says "creating instance from variable name", but it looks like you are trying to access `testClass.test1`. This is **not** an instance of the `testClass` class, and you **aren't** creating it.

Comment: I don't understand the edited question. `eval(x + '.' + y + '=bead()')` doesn't work. You can't do an assignment in there. Are you asking for a way to dynamically create variables or are you asking something about the class?

Comment: yes. I'm trying to dynamically create an instance of a class from a variable of a string.

Comment: @jHoro, you'd better cut-and-paste rather than type your questions in. your examples never work as typed.

Comment: For edit2, you can just use `locals()[x].printmsg()`. If the method name is a variable (eg `y='printmsg'`) also, you can do it exactly as in my answer. Since you are calling it, you would need to add `()` to the end like this `getattr(locals()[x], y)()`

Answer (score 12):

Instead of the `eval()`, you could say

```
getattr(locals()[x], y)
```

or

```
getattr(locals().get(x), y)
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: thank you for the answer. However I didn't phrase the question well. Please notice the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand. What you probably want is:

```
>>> class testClass():
...     test1='test1 text'
... 
>>> getattr(testClass, 'test1')
'test1 text'
```

---

Still that isn't creating an instance. Riffing on gnibbler's answer, here you make an instance:

```
>>> locals().get(x)()
<__main__.testClass instance at 0xb73b056c>
>>> getattr(locals().get(x)(), y)
'test1 text'
```

For your latest edit:

```
>>> class bead():
...     def printmsg(a):
...         print('test message')
... 
>>> chain1=bead()
>>> x='chain1'
>>> eval(x + '.printmsg()')
test message
>>> getattr(locals()[x], 'printmsg')()
test message
```

Comment: But that is : "testClass" not testClass